# Progress Update in AsyncTask , Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am new to android. I am trying to use asyncTask. I understand there is something called as onProgressUpdate.

I am downloading data from online server and total data is about 2000.

in Background Async I have done the following inside the for loop I keep publishing the value of I. something like this:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(JSONArray... params)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < params[0].length(); i++)
  {
     //I DO MY BACKGROUND PROCESS

     publishProgress(i);                   
  }
return null;
```

}

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            Log.e("Value", "onProgressUpdate - " + values[0]);
        }
```

This actually prints count one by one until 2000. Now how would I make to show when the count in percentage. Like 1%, 2% till 100%.

Thanks

Comment: Log.e("Value", "onProgressUpdate - " + ((values[0]/2000)*100)+"%");

Comment: @KhizarHayat.. that will show 2000%

Comment: Sorry i was updated before :P

Comment: Now Check sorry formula was wrong before hope now it will work

Comment: You likely do not need to publish progress after processing each item. If you have 200 items, it will cause 2000 notifications sent to the UI thread, while you need to process 20 items for the percentage number to change.

Comment: @KhizarHayat: I tried that. I am getting value 0 always.

Comment: @18446744073709551615: I am actually doing .length of the string. so I won have an issue.

Comment: impossible. it will for sure give you right answer. (values[0]/2000)*100 is percentage formula

Comment: @user6060320 use Double instead of Integer try my answer

Comment: @user6060320 did you solve your problem?

Comment: Not yet. checking.

Comment: @Amy: I am getting values like this: http://www.beetxt.com/XeE/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is stated in the comments, but it is safer to calculate dynamically, rather than hardcoded to 2000.

```
AsyncTask<JSONArray, Integer, String> task = new AsyncTask<JSONArray, Integer, String>() {
            private int maxProgress;

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(JSONArray... params) {

                maxProgress = params[0].length();
                for (int i = 0; i < maxProgress; i++) {
                    //I DO MY BACKGROUND PROCESS

                    publishProgress(i);
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                Log.e("Value", "onProgressUpdate - " + (values[0] * 100 / maxProgress) + "%");
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Use double value instead of Integer

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Double... values) {
double percentage = (values[0]/2000)*100;
            Log.e("Value", "onProgressUpdate - " + percentage+"%");
}
```

Comment: it means calculation is right if want to shorten the value you can do it using Math.floor methos :)

Comment: OK. Let me know check on it. Thanks!